# Struts2 validation and Select tag

Tags: validation, struts2, annotations

I'm using struts2 and validation using annotations in the action. I do use another action to fill the select lists when i fill the form with missing data it returns to the input result of the action but with the missing list and shows me an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the [FAQ entry about repopulating form controls when validation fails](http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/how-do-we-repopulate-controls-when-validation-fails.html).

The nutshell version is that if you have lists they need to be repopulated using either the `Preparable` interface or with `<s:action>` tags. Personally, I think `Preparable` is the way to go.